# Data rendering in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Each user has certain vacations that he adds. I want to render his vacations and not anyone else's. What should I do?

The view below shows all vacations, but I only want to show the vacations of a particular user.

```py
def all_vacations(request):
    vacations = Vacation.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'homePage.html', {'vacations': vacations})
```

Comment: Show your `urls.py` file.

Comment: path("all/", views.all_Vacations, name="all"),
    path('create/', views.create_vacation, name='create'),
     path('update/<int:id>/', views.changeVacationInfo, name='update'),
     path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
     path('login/', views.signin, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('', views.first , name='first')
]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

- Your URLs:

```py
path('users', views.users_view, name='users')
path('vacation/<int:pk>/', views.user_vacations, name='user_vacation')
```

- Create a view:

```py
# You have to create a view to list users
# List your users
def users_view(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'users': users})
```

- Create a template to list users:

```html
<!--In your template:-->

{% for user in users %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'user_vacation' user.id %}">{{ user}}</a></li>
<ul>
{% empty %}
    <!-- Do something -->
{% endfor %}
```

- Lastly, you return what you want:

```py
def user_vacations(request, id):
    vacations = Vacation.objects.get(author__id=id)
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'vacations': vacations})
```

Comment: class Vacation(models.Model):
    vacationInformation = models.TextField()
    startDate= models.DateTimeField('start date')
    endDate = models.DateTimeField('end date')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self. author


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField()
    email= models.EmailField()
    vacation = models.ForeignKey(Vacation,null=True , on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

Comment: here is my mdels

Comment: bro the comment isnt visible

Comment: deal bro it is okay

Comment: it didnt work it said that there is no view caled user_vacations

Comment: Reverse for 'user_vacations' not found. 'user_vacations' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly as it is there. I mean that you must create a url so that a view can list, in an html template, all users - ```User.objects.all ()```. In this template, you must create a link (URL) that must pass the user's id to your view. Within this, you can filter the vacation by user - ```Vaction.objects.get (author__id = id)``` .

Take a look at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Man, I did not undestand the relantionship between the models. In your User has
```vacation = models.ForeignKey(Vacation, null=True , on_delete=models.SET_NULL)``` and in your Vacation, ```author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)```. If it is a 1: n ratio, you must put the FK in Vacation and take this field from the other. Attention should also be paid to the sequence in which they are defined. In your models.py, the User class must come first

Comment: Take a look in my edit answer. Maybe this error is because the url ```path('vacation/<int:pk>', views.user_vacations, name='user_vacation')```. Change for ```path('vacation/<int:pk>/', views.user_vacations, name='user_vacation')```. And If the relantioship is a ManyToMany, you have to do ManyToManyField in Vacantion Model, ok? I hope I've helped.